# Why does \tikzset{every picture/.style={x=1pc, y=1pc}} break pgfplots scaling?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have run into a weird problem with TikZ and pgfplots. For regular TikZ drawings I set the scale with `\tikzset{every picture/.style={x=1pc, y=1pc}}`, but when after that I try to make a plot with a given width and height, it looks like unit vectors are not rescaled. For example, the following code compiles to a huge plot, which does not even fit on the page.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={x=1pc, y=1pc}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=20pc, height=20pc]
        \addplot{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried adding/changing `x=..., y=...` options both to `axis` and `tikzpicture` environments with close to no effect. As long as the `\tikzset{...}` line is commented out, everything works as expected.

How can I both set default unit vectors for regular `tikzpicture`s and at the same time have the plots scaled correctly?